# My css file didn't work, until i change the name of my css file

Tags: html, css

```html
<head>
 <title>weshop | barang-barang elektronik</title>
 <link href="<?php echo BASE_URL."css/style.css"; ?>" type="text/css" rel ="stylesheet" />  
</head>
```

I used php to write a code, in the first day, I put/save all file in such organized directory, and it worked, but the next day i tried to edit my css code, the changes didn't any effect, the style still look like the previous day. Then i tried to change the name of my css file, and IT WORKED!.. i was glad it worked, but the problem is, i don't know why it worked. here is my new css file name:

```html
<head>
 <title>weshop | barang-barang elektronik</title>
 <link href="<?php echo BASE_URL."css/newstyle.css"; ?>" type="text/css" rel ="stylesheet" />  
</head>
```

Comment: Refresh the browser cache using CTRL + F5 css is cached by the browser

Comment: welcome to the *cache world*

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 4):

CSS is cached by your browser.

When you amend your css code, you have to tell the browser to refresh its cache.

Do that by doing a CTRL + F5 on all the browsers you are using to test your code after making the change to the CSS file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can force the browser cache by CTRL + F5.

Alternatively you can delete the browser cronology also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Even after doing the above if you are unable to get the latest code, then you can try the following:

- Open file code through view page source in browser and either refresh with  <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

*or*

- Clear browser cache and reload the page

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's really helpful